# Denoise/smooth DEM in GRASS GIS using r.denoise addon

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, geotiff-tiff, dem, grass-7.0

I'm trying to denoise/smooth a digital elevation model (TIFF) file on GRASS GIS using r.denoise add-on. I cannot get it to work.

I don't know what to enter in the output box, my goal is to create a new TIFF file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use arbitrary names. For example, set `dem_denoised`. The denoised raster data will be created in working mapset as name `dem_denoised`.

Unlike the GDAL tools or QGIS, GRASS GIS stores spatial data once in the GRASS database, and the processed data is also stored in the database.
To output the stored data to a tiff file, etc., please use [r.out.gdal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.out.gdal.html).